# angularjs Check input field to prevent submission of SQL injection-like strings

Tags: angularjs

I have an input field in AngularJS and I want to do a submission check for SQL injection-like strings. Basically, I don't want SQL injection strings to pass the validation check. What's the best way to get this done?

Here is the HTML part:

```
<rb-input-text ng-model="textareaText" name="text" placeholder="" rb-change="" type="" maxlines="3" minlength="1" maxlength="1000">
</rb-input-text>
```

How it looks on the page:

[image]

Comment: You can use form validation in Angular : http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-pattern` to define a pattern that match your data.

However don't consider using this to prevent SQL-Injection. SQL Injection is a **matter of backend**. If your data can contains problematics character like `'` `#` you shouldn't need to forbid them on frontend. You MUST proceed them in the backend. All tools used to communicate with database provides functions to prevent SQL Injection. Use those tools and never, absolutely never do the following :

```
Select * from toto where name='+userInput+'.
```

Every tools you use provides you something to rewirte your query like this :

```
Select * from toto where name=? and lastname=?
```

Or this

```
Select * from toto where name=:name and lastname=:lastname
```